# Using a pull subscription with a long running process

Tags: python, google-app-engine, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have something like this in my `main.py`:

```
while (True):
    pulled = subscription.pull(max_messages=1) # also tried with return_immediately=True
    for ack_id, data in pulled:
        subscription.acknowledge([ack_id])
        run_task() # takes 15 minutes to return
    time.sleep(30)
```

What I'm trying to do is get a message from the queue, acknowledge it immediately and then run my long running job.

But every single time, just after 10 minutes of `run_task()` starting I get the following error on the `subscription.pull` line:

> "google.gax.errors.GaxError: GaxError(RPC failed, caused by
>   <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE,
>   {..."description":"Endpoint read failed"...}

I can tell that this error happens before `run_task()` finishes, but there are no exceptions thrown from inside `run_task()`. I have no idea how `run_task()` stopped and `pull()` is getting executed now.

Can anyone tell what's going on here? I'm kinda thinking that the message isn't being acknowledged and the acknowledgment deadline expires, but the message never gets re-delivered so that theory isn't adding up.